# Cannot Connect to IM Server Running on Guest Machine

Tags: linux, macos, server, chat, openfire

I have an IM Server(open fire) running as a guest(Linux, Ubuntu 18.4) on my Mac(Host). The guest is running with Bridged Connection settings. I can access Openfire admin console from my browser on the host machine(using: localhost:9090/) However I can't connect to the server using spark client on either the host or the guest. The domain name I used when creating the server was chatlink.com

How can I solve this? Eventually, I want to create my own client, Could you point me to some resources on how to create my own XMPP client?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a completely different question in the end. So i will try to answer just first one. First, you are saying that you connect to localhost:9090 on the host. Maybe you actually mean on the guest? Because if server is installed on the guest, that would make more sense. I also guess that chatlink.com is a fake domain you have made up. This won't work just like that with non existing domains. There should be something backing your domain name, like DNS. You can still make it "work". On host, in Spark, on login screen leave chatlink.com in Domain field, but go to Advanced menu, uncheck Automatic discovery of host and port and put IP of your guest VM there. You can find out its IP on Ubuntu running ifconfig command.